# Ball won't load up for game

Tags: javascript, css, html

```js
// Main Javascript
//Variables to use
var canvas;
var context;
var ball;

canvas = documnet.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getcontext("2d");

//Creates my ball function based off of what is on canvas for ball
ball = new Ball();
```

Well my ball is not showing up on screen and I am pretty sure I have done everything correctly but can someone look over it and find something I missed or made a mistake on? I really need some help and I appreciate the help!

*I have two Javascript files in here because I have one for my main javascript and ball*

```
//ball.js
function ball() {
  //The ball itself
  this.startAngle = 0;
  this.endAngle = 360 * Math.PI * 2;
  this.radius = 40;
  this.drawBall = true;

  //location for my ball
  this.x = canvs / width / 2;
  this.y = canvas / height / 2;

  //coloring my ball
  this.color = " #00FFFF";

  //draw function    
  this.draw = function () {
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.beginPath();
    content.arc(this.x, this.y, this.redius, this.startAngle, this.Endangle, this.drawBall);
    context.fill();
  }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" >
<title>Robert's Ball Game</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href = css/robs.css" />
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="720"></canvas>
</body>
//Javascript
<script type="text/javascript" src= "javas/ball.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "javas/rob.js"> </script>
</html>
```

Comment: in my Rob.js is this but it might not be right because I am having trouble

Comment: //Variables to use
var canvas;
var context;
var ball;

canvas = documnet.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getcontext("2d");

//Creates my ball function based off of what is on canvas for ball
ball = new Ball();

Comment: I am linking my js files to my html

Comment: I inserted the other Javascript file into my post.

Comment: Did you check the browser's dev console for errors yet? (If you don't know what that is, in most browsers pressing F12 opens up some dev tools, including a console where errors are displayed.) You have (at least) three problems: (1) You've spelled `document` incorrectly. (2) you call `new Ball()` but your function name has a lowercase "b" - JS is case sensitive, so use an uppercase "B" for the function name and a lowercase "b" for the instance. (3) You don't ever call the `draw()` function.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getcontext is not a function

Comment: ^What the console said and I fixed all the other thinks listed.

Comment: @Rob -- in addition to the spelling error nnnnnn mentioned (documnet), you are also missing a quotation mark in your stylesheet link. It might be a good start to proofread your js and other files before getting too carried away with debugging.

Comment: If you get an error that `x` is not a function then double-check what `x` is. In this case it's another capitalisation problem, where it should be `.getContext()` with a capital "c". Fix that, try again, fix the next error (if there is one), etc. If you get to a point where you can't progress, [edit] your question to show the current version of your code and ask specifically about the error you're stuck on. If you get no errors at all and the code still doesn't do anything make sure you call the functions.

Comment: Fixed them but to link my function I can't just link my js file to html?

Comment: After `ball = new Ball();` you would need `ball.draw()` to actually call that method.

Comment: Nothing comes up still

Answer (score 0):

You've got lots of spelling and capitalisation errors, and you hadn't actually called the `ball.draw()` function.

I've added comments in the code below to show what I've changed to make it work (click "run" to see the result):

```js
var canvas;
var context;
var ball;

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // "document", not "documnet"
context = canvas.getContext("2d");   // needs capital "C" in getContext

//Creates my ball function based off of what is on canvas for ball
ball = new Ball();
ball.draw();   // you didn't call .draw()

//ball.js
function Ball() {
  //The ball itself
  this.startAngle = 0;
  this.endAngle = 360 * Math.PI * 2;
  this.radius = 40;
  this.drawBall = true;

  //location for my ball
  this.x = canvas.width / 2;    // you had canvs / width / 2
  this.y = canvas.height / 2;   // you had canvas / height / 2

  //coloring my ball
  this.color = "#00FFFF";

  //draw function    
  this.draw = function () {
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.beginPath();
    // on next line you had "content" instead of "context",
    // and "Endangle" instead of "endAngle", and "redius" instead of "radius":
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.startAngle, this.endAngle, this.drawBall);
    context.fill();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```